# migrating database from development to production - rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database

Sorry if the question seems too simple, but I am quite new to rails. I generated scaffold in development mode. Then I migrated the database and it edited the mysql `app_development` table but not the mysql `app_production` table . Is there a specific command to migrate it also to the production table ?

Comment: RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate will do it.  normally your deploy scripts should handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you're saying is that you didn't use migrations to perform some changes and now rake db:migrate doesn't produce the database structure that you want (obviously, because it has no idea that you made those changes), you still can use the schema.rb.

```
rake db:schema:dump
```

Will read the db and generate a schema.rb for it. Then you can load this schema.rb on production with

```
rake db:schema:load RAILS_ENV=production
```

Also, you can delete everything and create the database from scratch using the schema.rb file with

```
rake db:reset RAILS_ENV=production
```

Answer (score 0):

For window just write 
db:migrate
and for Linux sudo rake db:migrate